# how to show videos in line with php and html?

Tags: php, html, css

Here's my HTML and PHP code but videos shown in vertical line, i use `inline-block` in CSS code but it doesn't work.

Please help me i am new to this.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="grid">
   <div class="preview">
      <a title="<?php echo $video_title; ?>
         "href="watch.php?videoid=<?php echo $video_id;?>">
            <img src="videos/thumbnails/<?php echo    $thumbnail;?> " />
      </a>
      <div class="time">00.00</div>
   </div>
   <div class="data">
      <h3><a href="watch.php?videoid=<?php echo $video_id;?>">
           <?php  echo substr( $video_title,0,19);?>
           <?php  echo substr( $video_title,19,20);?>
          </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="video-watch">
         <a href="watch.php?videoid">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
      <div class="lables">
         <p>Uploaded by:<a <?php if (isset($_SESSION['usr_name']))?>>
               <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name'] ;?>
                 </a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <?php } }?>   
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use an iframe?

Comment: Sir, I don't understand how to use and where to use this tag in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Use an IFrame.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
```